# Can a redux action both dispatch and return something in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have set up my redux properly: store, actions, reducers, I've mapped state to props etc and I am using redux thunk.

This is what my current actions look like:

[image]

I normally use my actions like this inside my components and it works just fine:

```js
this.props.addCars(newCar)
```

Sometimes I want to add a new car and in the next line do something with the new data using this.props.cars

`This.props.cars` does not show the car I just recently added though and using a Promise, or await like this does not work

```js
await this.props.addCars(newCar)
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to make my actions dispatch and return the data response.

Comment: when you say in the "next line" you mean right after you dispatch the action?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the response from axios and then dispatch the results plus return. Something like this.

```
 export async function addCars(car){
  var result = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/cars', car)
               .then((resp)=>
                {
                  return resp.data
                }


  dispatch({type: ADD_CAR, payload: result});
  return result;
}
```

Comment: and how would I use the receive the result being returned by this function in my component?

Comment: in that function you can call something that will set the state of your component.